# Who is Katakuri's father, do we know his race?

Tags: one-piece

Do we know anything about Katakuri's father or race? His teeth kind of remind me of Bartolomeo.

Comment: No definitive answers, only theories : https://www.reddit.com/r/OnePiece/comments/8dqkb1/katakuris_father_spoilers/

Comment: Dellinger's teeth are naturally pointed. It is worth noting that the other two triplets don't have that mouth.